# Run a Powershellscript by clicking a button on HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, powershell

I'm trying to find out, how I can run a simple powershellscript by clicking on a button. What am I doing wrong?

I tried the following:

`<input type="button"> onclick="<?php hello.ps1; ?>">`

and this one:

```
<input type="button" onclick="hello.ps1" value="Send" name="button"/>
```

Inside the .ps1 is the following:

```
Write-Output "Hello World"
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the powershell script to run on the server or the client?

Comment: It should run on both instances, is there a simple solution?